# can't work out the Minus Front

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

I'm supposed to have a result like the picture on the left when I click minus front but all I'm getting is like the picture on the right. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `Align to Pixel Grid` activated? It can sometimes cause problems like this when using Pathfinder. You should deactivate it :) There is a checkbox when you set up a New Document and you can change it afterwards in the Transform panel.

Comment: The picture on the left is **before** the Minus Front button is clicked... the picture on the right is **after** it's been clicked. Images in the middle are overlapping multiple shapes, not one object. Looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Minus front cuts off everything covered by the top object. The picture on the right is how it should look.

Comment: as much as you're right, OP was possibly inquiring about the change in the shape, look at the top part. But I guess we'll never know for sure...